# Check Map in Gatling

Tags: scala, gatling

I have problem with gatling. I have my json response

```
"data": [
  {
    "id": "memory1",
    "value": 10
  },
  {
    "id": "memory2",
    "value": 12
  },
  {
    "id": "memory3",
    "value": 13
  }
]
```

and then i do post several times (with `atOnceUsers(100)`)
and my response is

```
"data": [
      {
        "id": "memory2",
        "value": 1024
      },
      {
        "id": "memory3",
        "value": 1234
      },
      {
        "id": "memory1",
        "value": 1239
      }
    ]
```

I have different order in second json every time. So, I want to save my first response json as map, then I want to add values for each "id", and after this I want to check my Map with new responce json. There are many fields in json, but I need only value for each id. How can i do it?

Comment: so you want to be able to compare your first response subsequent ones and they should all be the same (except for the ordering in the json array)?

Comment: when I get my first response json, i dont know about values, but i know, what values will be in seconds json (i just will take my first values and add for each constant value), then i want to equal my values with second response from server